# remove an element from mongodb collection mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my post object:

```
    {
      active: true,
      images: [],
      mentions: [ '5f188433929c0e1e5c2c120f' ],
      tags: [ 5f1ae7c64cda4924dfdeb052 ],
      likes: [
        {
          _id: 5f1e8dd13ad9a05033643086,
          time: '2020-07-27T08:18:25.280Z',
          user: 5f188433929c0e1e5c2c120f,
          __v: 0
        },
        {
          _id: 5f1ea385a32c155d2ffd1e4d,
          time: '2020-07-27T09:51:01.542Z',
          user: 5f188298929c0e1e5c2c120e,
          __v: 0
        }
      ],
      dislikes: [],
      comments: [
        5f1d622d6f2dcc10348914e6,
        5f1d63b642517616cbeb6350,
      ],
      _id: 5f1c1db77406961907c6ffc8,
      creator: 5f188298929c0e1e5c2c120e,
      time: '2020-07-25T11:55:35.897Z',
    }
```

I'm trying to remove a like from it using

```
    await Post.update(
        { _id: postId },
        {
           $pull: {
             likes: {
               user: "5f188298929c0e1e5c2c120e",
            },
           },
       },
       { safe: true, multi: true, session: sess }
   );
```

Schemas of post and like are as below. Let me know in comments if someone needs the user schema too.

Post schema

```
     const postSchema = new Schema({
       active: {
         type: Boolean,
         default: true,
       },
       creator: {
         type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
         required: true,
         ref: "User",
       },
       time: {
         type: String,
         required: true,
       },
       text: {
         type: String,
         required: true,
       },
       images: [
         {
           type: String,
         },
       ],
       mentions: [
         {
           type: String,
         },
       ],
       tags: [
         {
           type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "Tag",
         },
       ],
       likes: [
         {
           type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "Like",
         },
       ],
       dislikes: [
         {
           type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "Like",
         },
       ],
       comments: [
         {
           type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "Comment",
         },
       ],
     });
```

Like schema

```
     const likeSchema = new Schema({
       time: {
         type: String,
         required: true,
       },
       user: {
         type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
         required: true,
         ref: "User",
       },
     });
```

This is'nt working. This ain't throwing any error but it just doesn't remove the like object. I used Post.update() and Post.findOneAndUpdate(). Both of them are'nt working

Comment: What is the type of `_id` and `user` ? What is the value of `postId`?

Comment: type of _id is mongoose object id and value of postId is 5f1c1db77406961907c6ffc8

Comment: Have you tried  `_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(postId)` ?

Comment: yeah just did! Same thing

Comment: How about `user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f188298929c0e1e5c2c120e")` ?

Comment: still same. Tried ObjectId() on both of them

Comment: `{ safe: true, multi: true, session: sess }` The Mongoose docs on [Model#update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) doesn't have all the options you are using.

Comment: removed the safe and session options. Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't figure out the solution or the problem with the code I was using but for time being I've used a different way of removing an object from a mongoose array which itself is a schema. Here is my code;

```
const identifiedPost = await Post.findById(postId).populate("likes");
identifiedPost.likes = identifiedPost.likes.filter((like) => {
  //like.user is a objectId here
  return like.user.toString() !== userId.toString();
});
```

**NOTE:** Please make sure you use toString() for both the objectId's otherwise this won't work properly